# pyodbc insert statement gets error message

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to insert value into SQL SERVER using python.
I wrote my python program as below.

```
import pyodbc
import subprocess
cnx = pyodbc.connect("DSN=myDSN;UID=myUID;PWD=myPassword;port=1433")
runcmd1 = subprocess.check_output(["usbrh", "-t"])[0:5]
runcmd2 = subprocess.check_output(["usbrh", "-h"])[0:5]
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM T_TABLE-A;")
cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO T_TABLE-A (TEMP,RH,DATE,COMPNAME)
                VALUES
                (runcmd1,runcmd2,GETDATE(),'TEST_Py')
                ''')
cnx.commit()
```

Then get error like below.

```
# python inserttest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inserttest.py", line 13, in <module>
    ''')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'runcmd1'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

If I wrote like below, it's OK to insert.

```
import pyodbc
cnx = pyodbc.connect("DSN=myDSN;UID=myUID;PWD=myPassword;port=1433")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM T_TABLE-A;")
cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO T_TABLE-A (TEMP,RH,DATE,COMPNAME)
                VALUES
                (20.54,56.20,GETDATE(),'TEST_P')
                ''')
cnx.commit()
```

The command USBRH -t gets temperature and USBRH -h gets humidity. They work well in individual python program.
Does anyone have idea to solve this error?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO T_TABLE-A (TEMP,RH,DATE,COMPNAME)
                VALUES
                (runcmd1,runcmd2,GETDATE(),'TEST_Py')
                ''')
```

won't work because you are embedding the *names* of the Python variables, not their *values*. You need to do

```py
sql = """\
INSERT INTO T_TABLE-A (TEMP,RH,DATE,COMPNAME)
VALUES
(?, ?, GETDATE(),'TEST_Py')
"""
cursor.execute(sql, runcmd1, runcmd2)
```

Comment: Hello Gord. Thanks a lot reply me again. You help me before and this time. As you directed me I changed and it works! I do not understand "?" in your answer but it can perfectly insert values into table. really really helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

check the data types returning from these two lines

```
runcmd1 = subprocess.check_output(["usbrh", "-t"])[0:5]
runcmd2 = subprocess.check_output(["usbrh", "-h"])[0:5]
```

`runcmd1` and `runcmd2` should be in 'double' data type since it accepts `20.54`.

Comment: The column data type is decimal. If I wrote directly the value, its no problem to INSERT.